# Anyone get the Zoom H6 yet?

Tags: zoom, handheld

It's not shipping yet, but i didn't know if anyone got to check out a pre-release or press release that was about to say anything about.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small comparison between the H4n and the H6. The H6 seems to be a good value, but is definetly too big for me to carry around every day...
check the full comparison and audio previews here...
http://bit.ly/16mqT4R